# Enforce table ownership

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Here's the deal,: I have postgresql databases (GCP Cloud SQL deployment, I don't care about version) and I want to enforce ownership of tables.

Specifically, an application logs in to the database `mydb` via GCP IAM account, which has assigned `role_admin`. The application needs to create a table `mytable` owned by `role_mydb_admin`. So it needs to first call `SET ROLE role_mydb_admin;` and then proceed to create the table.
Here's how the ownership looks like:

```
Role                  | Member of
----------------------+-----------------
user@gcpprojectid.iam | role_admin
role_admin            | role_mydb_admin
```

```
Name    | Owner
--------+-----------------
mytable | role_mydb_admin
```

If, for some reason, the user does not set the role to `role_mydb_admin`, the table will be created under the `role_admin`. That is a problem I need to avoid.

One way to get around this is to create a function that will intercept CREATE TABLE via event trigger and reassign incorrectly created tables. That works but is not a good enough solution, because some applications are performing a lot of DDL manipulations as part of their work and it calls triggers this function excessively. Secondly, I don't like it.

What I would like would be some kind of policy, which would ensure that the table can be created only with `role_mydb_admin` user. Is something like this possible? Something like `deny create table if owner not equal to role_mydb_admin`.

Or if I could have a `role_admin` which would simply not have the CREATE and ALTER permissions, but have the permission to SET ROLE to `role_mydb_admin` (which has these permissions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy; use an intermediate `NOINHERIT` role:

```
CREATE ROLE admin_noinherit NOLOGIN NOINHERIT;
REVOKE role_mydb_admin FROM "user@gcpprojectid.iam";
GRANT role_mydb_admin TO admin_noinherit;
GRANT admin_noinherit TO "user@gcpprojectid.iam";
```

Now `"user@gcpprojectid.iam"` (weird name) is a member of `role_mydb_admin`, but does not inherit permissions from that role.

Then change the schema so that only `role_mydb_admin` has the `CREATE` privilege. After that, `"user@gcpprojectid.iam"` *must* use

```
SET ROLE role_mydb_admin;
```

to be able to create a table, and the table ownership is as it should be.

Note, however, that there is nothing that keeps `"user@gcpprojectid.iam"` FROM running

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.tab SET OWNER TO "user@gcpprojectid.iam";
```

at some later point. But I guess you are only trying to establish reasonable default permissions.

Comment: Thank you, I did some experiments and your answer was exactly the part I needed to hear!
You do have a typo there though, as `role_admin` is essentially the intermediate role. You might want to update it for other readers.
As you said, it's more about defaults than about building a bunker.

P.S.: `user@gcpprojectid.iam` is a standard form generated by GCP IAM